# Crontab that executes shell script every minute

Tags: linux, shell, cron

I have made a shell script on my red hat server that needs to be run every minute. My script is located in `/media`. I have edited the crontab like so:

```
* * * * * /media/statusshellscript.sh
```

My script is definitely in the location above and I know that 5 stars means run every minute.

oh.. and my script definintely works! because when I do a ./statusshellscript it works fine. Here is my script anyway, it basically just runs a php script I made which made life easier.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script to execute the PHP Script

cd ~
cd /media/PHPServerTest
php -f index.php
```

Crontab is doing absolutely nothing at the moment. Not sure what to try next?

Also.. permissions shouldn't be a problem as i've done `chmod 777 statusshellscript`.

Comment: Wouldn't every minute be `*/1 * * * *`?

Comment: @Let_Me_Be Why not `*/1 */1 */1 */1 */1` then?

Comment: I'm not positive but I think * * * * * is the same thing. And nothing happens at all...

Comment: @rednaxela Check the execution rights. I have actually seen one setup, where `./script` would evaluate the script regardless of exec rights.

Comment: Show us the shell script. Also, redirect stderr in your crontab to catch errors `* * * * * /media/statusshellscript.sh 2>>/tmp/statusshellscript.errors`, and run `mail` for the user that the cron job is running as since errors can end up there too.

Comment: try running `/media/statusshellscript.sh` from prompt. ensure `PATH` env var is set to required locations.

Comment: I have edited my question now which shows my shell script.

Comment: Next, put and echo statement early in the script, and very the output is emailed to you. You may need to fix email setup of host to get that working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if its not running though **cronjob** but by **command** its working fine then there can be **two** reasons

1) you never made your file **executable** , that you can resolve my using the command

```
sudo chmod +x filename
```

2) your path is not correct , for finding absolute path you can use command

```
realpath(filename)
```

if **realpath** is not already installed it will mention you a command how to install it

by checking these points it should work fine.

Comment: I tried the 'sudo chmod +x filename' and nothing changes. Couldn't get the 'realpath()' to work but I did 'pwd' and got the same path I put in the   crontab.

Comment: `chmod +x filename` should _not_ be needed if `./filename` works, unless something new has happened. And a quick `ls -l filename` would tell OP which bits are set. I still think this is due to `PATH` not being correctly set in the crontab.

Comment: @rednaxela you can sudo realpath(filename) , by using chmod +x filename your file should be greenish if it was not before ....

Answer (score 0):

The `PATH` for a crontab is not the same as in a shell.

Make sure that you define a `PATH` in your crontab that includes everything that is needed by the script.

Also, make sure that the script starts with a valid `#!` marker that points at the desired shell.

Or, use the full path for *all* commands in the script.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, my bet would be a misconfigured PATH. Try putting this into your path:

"* * * * * /media/statusshellscript.sh"

Go check that output file to see the PATH when the script is run. And rather than defining your PATH in the crontab, just define it in your script.

Comment: I can't comment as lack of rep but try replacing ~ with your explicit home (/home/<username/)

Comment: Or actually removing the "cd ~" as it is useless